# Change background color whilst scrolling using jQuery waypoints

Tags: jquery, colors, jquery-waypoints

I want to gradually cycle through different background colors for a fixed div as you scroll down the page. I think I can do this using jQuery waypoints, but need a hand starting this as I have no idea where to start.

Website I'm working on is here: [www.samskirrowdesign.com](http://www.samskirrowdesign.com) I want to change the color of the 3px high fixed div at the top of the page.

Comment: I'd not use waypoints and react directly to `scroll`

Comment: `$('body, html').on('scroll', function() { if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100 ) $(this).css('background', 'red'); });`

Comment: thanks @adeneo this is what I have so far. It's not quite working though, any thoughts? 
`$('body, html').on('scroll', function() { if ($('body').scrollTop() > 100 ) $('.top').css('background-color', '#000'); });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your scroll top position you can have a gradient change like

```
   $(window).scroll(function () { 
    $('#test').css('background-color','#BC46'+($(this).scrollTop()/10))
    });
```

Look at this fiddle

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adKRU/)

Comment: Thanks @sayannayas - i'm convinced this will work, is there something slightly wrong with the syntax though as it's flagging up errors when I add it into dreamweaver...i'm sure it's something simple, but my jQuery knowledge isn't good